# How to pass a linked list as argument into a method and how to call it?

Tags: c#, linked-list

```
class Program
{

    public string name;
    public string cell;
    public Program(string a1,string c1)
    {
        name = a1;
        cell = c1;
    }

    public void DetailAccept()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter name :");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("enter cell :");
        cell = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public string getName()
    { 
     return name;
    }
    public string getCellNo()
    { return cell; }
    public void AddL(string a, string b, LinkedList<Program> linked)
    {
        Program p1 = new Program(a, b);
        linked.AddLast(p1);
    }

    public void menu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n Choose what to do :\n1. Add new Entry\n2. Search Phone\n3.quit\n");

        int choice = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: DetailAccept();
                AddL(getName(), getCellNo(), linked); // here is the problem . 

        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to pass the `LinkedList` as argument to use it in a function?  If yes then how, if no, what are the alternatives?

Comment: It seems you have some code in place already. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Instance fields, Properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you intend something like this?

```
private LnkedList<Program> _Programs = new LinkedList<Program>();

public void menu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n Choose what to do :\n1. Add new Entry\n2. Search Phone\n3.quit\n");

    int choice = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: DetailAccept();
            AddL(getName(), getCellNo(), _Programs);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped. I am new to programming and this was kind of stupid.